# Form validation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to develop an application windows phone 7.
And for obvious reasons I have to validate my forms.

I usually program in WPF and uses the principle of ValidationRule. But I can not find the same principle in windows phone 7.

Hence my question, how to create a form validation.

Comment: I will advertise my implementation of validation: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/windows-phone-7-validation. I think it is easier to use than other implementations in the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't support form validations out of the box.

Here's a [blog post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Building-WP7-Custom-Validation-Control---Architecture-amp-Basic-Prototype) that describes how to roll a custom control to implement validation rules.

The way I would handle this in one of my own apps would be to put the validation logic in my model class and create an `IsValid` property on the model. The model class would also have an `Error` property with an error message describing the validation issue. My UI layer would call `myModel.IsValid`, and display the error message if something was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the same approach that I used with Silverlight on desktops: the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) interface.

[Here](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/windows-phone-7-validation/) I described it more particularly, and [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/WordPress/WindowsPhoneValidation.zip) you can download source code of the sample project.

The simpliest example looks so:

**View.xaml**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
         Style="{StaticResource ValidationTextBoxStyle}" />
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingValidationError += MainPage_BindingValidationError;
}

private void MainPage_BindingValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var state = e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added ? "Invalid" : "Valid";

    VisualStateManager.GoToState((Control)e.OriginalSource, state, false);
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ValidationViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Validator.AddValidationFor(() => this.SomeProperty).NotEmpty().Show("Enter a value");
    }

    private string someProperty;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
        set
        {
            someProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

It relies on lots of supplementary classes, but at the same time there are little code that you will write by yourself.